# Enabling PHP errors when creating a CSV file from database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

This method for exporting data on csv has worked previously on other projects, but I can not make this work on here, and I am not sure about how to enable erros for this case.

This PHP file creates a comma-separated file containing an initial row with a single tab ("ID"), and then it should be creating a row for each match on the SELECT query from DB

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();

include('conexionbbdd.php');

    $file='informes/expositores_'.time().'.xls';

    header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");  
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
    header("Expires: 0");        

    $output = fopen($file, 'w');

    fwrite($output, chr(239) . chr(187) . chr(191)); 

    fputcsv($output, array('ID'), "\t");    

    // fetch the data
    $rows1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ex_id FROM expositores WHERE ex_id = '26'");

    // loop over the rows, outputting them
    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows1)) {     
        fputcsv($output, $row1, "\t");        
    }

    fclose($output);
    echo $file;


ob_end_flush();   
?>
```

In this particular case I've simplified this to maximu so, apart from the initial row, a unique row containg the "26" should be created (I've tested that the query works with PhpMyAdmin, there's an ID 26). But it does not.

It only creates correctly first row from this first `fputcsv` method:

```
fputcsv($output, array('ID'), "\t");
```

No other row seems to be fetched or placed on the CSV.

As the entire PHP file's aim is to create the CSV file, no error is shown because it does not open on a new window.

Output:

[image]

Comment: What is the question? Have you checked your error logs? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I think instead of insert array you have to insert there values as `fputcsv($output, $row1['ex_id'], "\t"); `

Comment: if `ex_id` is an int, then remove the quotes `WHERE ex_id = 26");`

Comment: @JayBlanchard that made me solve the issue. I was using myslqi on a mysql project. I did not know how to view errors on this case. Please type that as an answer to tick and explain for other users.

Comment: @Saty, the file creates correctly the CSV as seen on the question. The mistake was on using mysqli and not knowing how to check errors on these cases.

Comment: actually this question should be closed with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php

Comment: @Fred-ii- what about changing the title to focus it on PHP error viewing? That would make this question useful for the community.

Comment: well, *technically speaking*, the question would be a duplicate of "Mixing MySQL APIs". Since the connection details are/were unknown, then I think we should just leave well enough alone. You can change the title if you wish, however mixing MySQL APIs is the real issue here.

Comment: Yes, this question would be related to that one, but sincerelly my problem was about nort knowing the issue reason (solved after error enabling) rather than ignoring possibilities of mixing MySQL APIs. If this must be deleted/marked as duplicate please proceed. Thank you.

Comment: No, like I said; let's leave it the way it is. This one's a bit tricky but I like the question. Your code could be useful for others. @Biomehanika

Comment: Note that you're also writing a CSV file and pretending it's XLS. This *will* bite you, sooner or later.

Comment: Uhm... I've used this system for a year without issues, the only thing is that you have to open thje file trough the OPEN menu on Excel, in order to tabulate each coma-separated value on each tab. Have you got any idea of which kind of problems could this cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to solve this you will need to be able to view the errors. You can have a look in your error logs or add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: After enabling errors, it was clear that I was using mysqli on a mysql project.